# What is query speed or difference between Django ForeignKey and OneToOneField

Tags: django

I've seen this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/VEDZtuND2XM

But on that answer, Ronaldo said just about convenience not the speed of query speed.

Is there speed or performance difference between ForeignKey(unique=true) and OneToOneField?

Or is there any other advantages on using OneToOneField than ForeignKey(unique=true) ?

Comment: The reverse access to the instance is more intuitive: FK: `rel_model_instance.related_name.get()`, 1to1: `rel_model_instance.related_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is no. But there is some performance difference if you doing some general stuff on reverse relations: when you use reverse relations defined via `OneToOneField` you get an model instance, contrary to Manager for `ForeignKey` reverse relation and as a consequence there's always a database hit - and this is costly.